# Suggestion needed: Spree Commerce Wombat Integration

Tags: spree, mandrill

I'm new to spree commerce and migrating from Magento. I was trying to integrate Mandril. What I found is this:

In Magento:   Site => MangeMonkey Plugin => Mandrill

What I found in documentation for spree is this:

Site => Wombat => Mandrill

instead of:

Site => Mandrill Gem => Mandrill

Am I correct?

Now Wombat is a paid system which contradicts the 0$ policy of spree. My question is it a compulsion to use Wombat with spree?

Any blog link or suggestion for integration will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you could easily override the rails default mailer and provide mandrill smtp credentials. using something like this https://github.com/renz45/mandrill_mailer

Comment: Thanks kitwalker, I'll give it a try today